# how to speed data loading XML file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml, performance

I've got a 2Gb XML file that I want to load into a single table in MySQL.

The number of records/rows is ~140,000, but the default behavior of the LOAD XML function in MYSQL seems to depart from linear time.

Cutting the data into smaller pieces, I get the following performance (dropped table between each LOAD)

all were: Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

5000 row(s) affected Records: 5000      4.852 sec

10000 row(s) affected Records: 10000    20.670 sec

15000 row(s) affected Records: 15000    80.294 sec

20000 row(s) affected Records: 20000    202.474 sec

The XML is well formed.  I've tried:
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;

What can I do to load it in a reasonable time that doesn't involve cutting it into a dozen pieces?

Comment: please show the code you're using to load the datas

Comment: What indexes do you have defined on the table into which the data is inserted?

Comment: @Sebas: See [`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html).

Comment: use test;

DROP TABLE clinical_study;

CREATE TABLE clinical_study (
    id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 required_header_download_date VARCHAR(160) NULL,
 required_header_link_text VARCHAR(160) NULL,
 required_header_url VARCHAR(160) NULL,
 id_info_org_study_id VARCHAR(160) NULL,
 id_info_secondary_id VARCHAR(160) NULL,
 id_info_nct_id VARCHAR(160) NULL,
 brief_title VARCHAR(500) NULL,
 ...truncated to meet character limit...

);

Comment: SHOW WARNINGS;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;


LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 
'C:\\Users\\212308962\\Documents\\Projects\\ClinicalTrials_FDA_gov\\ct_fda_2013_01_07_search_result\\all_parse.out'
INTO TABLE clinical_study
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<clinical_study>';

Comment: @eggyal, added CONCURRENT, zero performance change

Comment: basically you need to commit every x inserts, so yes cutting it might me your only solution aside of dropping indexes as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the indexes before the load, then rebuilding them afterward.

Comment: ALTER TABLE clinical_study drop index id;produces Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP 'id'; check that column/key exists